# Current power consumption

Tags: power

Is there a way to know the current (or average power consumption) on OS X (a Mac Mini without battery). Preferred would be a command line tool but anything is OK.

Comment: [Intel Power Gadget](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-power-gadget-20). I use it on my Mac mini and it works fine.

Answer (score 3):

You can monitoring your energy consumption with :

**iStat Menus :**

[image]
http://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/

*You also have some free alternative on the web*

**The Activity Monitor**

[image]
http://www.tekrevue.com/tip/use-activity-monitor-energy-tab-os-x-mavericks/

And if you want to know the kW energy consumption, ArchonOSX is right.

Answer (score 2):

I use a Kill a Watt to check track power consumption of household items.

[http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00009MDBU?keywords=kill%20a%20watt&qid=1447667271&ref_=sr_1_1&sr=8-1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00009MDBU)

By going with this you can also check other items in your household to see how much power they consume and reduce your energy use.